# I have a custom ODBC driver residing on a remote machine, anyway I can "share" it with my local machine?

Tags: odbc

I have a ODBC connection setup on a server (Windows 2003). The drivers are custom and they're the only way I can access the database. They work fine on this machine, but having to RDP to use Visual Studio on this Windows 2003 machine is a pain in the ass.

I can't install the ODBC package on my local machine (Windows 7) as the latest version of Windows the installer will allow is Windows 2003.

This is incredibly frustrating, are there any ways around this? It seems like I should be able to proxy into that ODBC connection somehow, but I've never dealt with such proprietary database access before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenLink Multi-Tier ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/) has been available for over 15 years and will enable the bridging between the Windows 7 client and Windows 2003 Server machine where the current ODBC Driver exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

[ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/)

I've never used it, but it's the best-known one